# Restrict mongoose field values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var FeelingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: String,
    feelingDate: Date,
    feelingTimeOfDay: String,
    feelingValue: String
  }
);
```

How do I restrict the value of the field feelingValue to a limited set, say ['happy', 'angry', 'shocked']

I'm using version 3.8.23 of mongoose

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can constrain a string field to a set of enumerated values with the [`enum`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) attribute in the schema definition:

```
var FeelingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: String,
    feelingDate: Date,
    feelingTimeOfDay: String,
    feelingValue: { type: String, enum: ['happy', 'angry', 'shocked'] }
  }
);
```